# Product Image Thumbnail Size

Tags: product-images, thumbnail, image-resize

The thumbnail image of some products are not uniform leading to weird size differences that throw them off. Here's an example to see it:

https://www.jadeed.store/categories/books/dictionaries.html

Need a solution that does not require me to manually adjust the images of each product as that is too time consuming.